# Денвер даёт такую ошибку, помогите разобраться, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in W:\home\localhost\www\test\sqltest.php on line 4

Tags: php, mysql, denwer

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!db_server) die ("Невозможно подключиться к MySQL: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)

    or die ("Невозможно выбрать базу данных: " . mysql_error());
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['isbn']))
{
    $isbn = get_post('isbn');
    $query = "DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn = '$isbn'";
    if (!mysql_db_query($query, $db_server))
        echo "Сбой при удалении данных: $query<br>" ,
        mysql_error() . "<br><br>";
}
if (isset($_POST['author']) &&
    isset($_POST['title']) &&
    isset($_POST['category']) &&
    isset($_POST['year']) &&
isset($_POST['isbn']))

{
        $author = get_post ('author');
        $title= get_post ('title');
        $category = get_post ('category');
        $year = get_post ('year');
        $isbn =  get_post ('isbn');    


    $query = "INSERT into classics VALUES" ,
    "('author', 'title','category' ,'year', 'isbn' )";
if (!mysql_db_query($query, $db_server))
    echo "Сбой при вставке данных: $query<br>" ,
    mysql_error() . "<br><br>";

}

echo <<<_END 
<form action ="sqltest.php" method="post"><pre>
Author <input type="text" name="author">
Title <input type="text" name="title">
Category <input type="text" name="category">
Year <input type="text" name="year">
ISBN <input type="text" name="isbn">
    <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD">
    </pre></form>
    _END;
$query = "SELECT* FROM classics";
$result = mysql_db_query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Сбой при доступе к базе данных: " . mysql_error());
{
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo <<<_END
<pre>
Author $row[0];
Title $row[1];
Category $row[2];
Year $row[3];
ISBN $row[4];
</pre>
<form action="sqltest.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes">
<input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="$row[4]">
<input type="submit" value = "DELETE RECORD"></form>
_END;
}

mysql_close($db_server);
function get_post ($var)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);

}

?>
```

Comment: @KoVadim вы зря помогли автору отформатировать код. Ведь ошибка у него именно где-то в форматировании и закралась - а теперь она потеряна.

Comment: я код не переделывал и не менял.

Comment: спасибо KoVadim

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка синтаксиса. Т.е. это PHP... не MySQL или Denwer. Это парсинг PHP.

Мне кажется, что проблема с heredoc-синтаксисом (http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

> использование heredoc-синтаксиса: <<<. После этого оператора
>   необходимо указать идентификатор, затем перевод строки. После этого
>   идет сама строка, а потом этот же идентификатор, закрывающий вставку.
>
> Строка должна начинаться с закрывающего идентификатора, т.е. он должен
>   стоять в первом столбце строки. Кроме того, идентификатор должен
>   соответствовать тем же правилам именования, что и все остальные метки
>   в PHP: содержать только буквенно-цифровые символы и знак
>   подчеркивания, и не должен начинаться с цифры (знак подчеркивания
>   разрешается).

Конкретно в Вашем случае, вот тут:

```
echo <<<_END 
<form action ="sqltest.php" method="post"><pre>
Author <input type="text" name="author">
Title <input type="text" name="title">
Category <input type="text" name="category">
Year <input type="text" name="year">
ISBN <input type="text" name="isbn">
    <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD">
    </pre></form>
    _END;
```

1. уберите пробел после начально идентификатора. Не `<<<_EOD`, а `<<<_EOD`.
2. убедитесь, что закрывающий идентификатор стоит в первом столбце строки. У Вас, похоже, сначала табуляция и только потом `_EOD;`. Уберите табуляцию. Строка должна состоять только из следующих 5 знаков `_EOD;`